# How to add Paypal to Payment in Django E-commerce Project

Tags: python, django, paypal

I have been searching on the best way to add the PayPal payment to my E-commerce Project, but I am currently stuck on where to start exactly, I have read the PayPal documentation found in
`https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/radio`

Currently when the user adds items to the cart, in the checkout page there is a form to be filled, so after adding the address there is a radio button to choose from it whether to proceed with Stripe or PayPal, so my question is what should I do so that when the PayPal radio is chosen it opens the PayPal login window?

Here is the models.py

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    stripe_charge_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Here is the views.py

```
class CheckoutView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            form = CheckoutForm()
            context = {
                'form': form,
                'couponform': CouponForm(),
                'order': order,
                'DISPLAY_COUPON_FORM': True
            }
            shipping_address_qs = Address.objects.filter(
                user=self.request.user,
                address_type='S',
                default='True'
            )
            if shipping_address_qs.exists():
                context.update(
                    {'default_shipping_address': shipping_address_qs[0]})

            billing_address_qs = Address.objects.filter(
                user=self.request.user,
                address_type='B',
                default='True'
            )
            if billing_address_qs.exists():
                context.update(
                    {'default_billing_address': billing_address_qs[0]})

            return render(self.request, "checkout.html", context)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.info(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("core:checkout")

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CheckoutForm(self.request.POST or None)
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            if form.is_valid():

                use_default_shipping = form.cleaned_data.get(
                    'use_default_shipping')
                if use_default_shipping:
                    print("Using the defualt shipping address")
                    address_qs = Address.objects.filter(
                        user=self.request.user,
                        address_type='S',
                        default=True
                    )
                    if address_qs.exists():
                        shipping_address = address_qs[0]
                        order.shipping_address = shipping_address
                        order.save()
                    else:
                        messages.info(
                            self.request, "No default shipping address available")
                        return redirect('core:checkout')
                else:
                    print("User is entering a new shipping address")
                    shipping_address1 = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'shipping_address')
                    shipping_address2 = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'shipping_address2')
                    shipping_province = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'shipping_province')
                    shipping_country = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'shipping_country')
                    shipping_postal_code = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'shipping_postal_code')
                    shipping_phone_number = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'shipping_phone_number')

                    if is_valid_form([shipping_address1, shipping_province, shipping_country, shipping_postal_code,
                                      shipping_phone_number]):
                        shipping_address = Address(
                            user=self.request.user,
                            street_address=shipping_address1,
                            apartment_address=shipping_address2,
                            province=shipping_province,
                            country=shipping_country,
                            postal_code=shipping_postal_code,
                            phone_number=shipping_phone_number,
                            address_type='S'
                        )
                        shipping_address.save()

                        order.shipping_address = shipping_address
                        order.save()

                        set_default_shipping = form.cleaned_data.get(
                            'set_default_shipping')
                        if set_default_shipping:
                            shipping_address.default = True
                            shipping_address.save()

                    else:
                        messages.info(
                            self.request, "Please fill in the required shipping address fields")

                use_default_billing = form.cleaned_data.get(
                    'use_default_billing')
                same_billing_address = form.cleaned_data.get(
                    'same_billing_address')

                if same_billing_address:
                    billing_address = shipping_address
                    billing_address.pk = None
                    billing_address.save()
                    billing_address.address_type = 'B'
                    billing_address.save()
                    order.billing_address = billing_address
                    order.save()

                elif use_default_billing:
                    print("Using the default billing address")
                    address_qs = Address.objects.filter(
                        user=self.request.user,
                        address_type='B',
                        default='True'
                    )
                    if address_qs.exists():
                        billing_address = address_qs[0]
                        order.billing_address = billing_address
                        order.save()
                    else:
                        messages.info(
                            self.request, "No default billing address available")
                        return redirect('core:checkout')
                else:
                    print("User is entering a new billing address")
                    billing_address1 = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'billing_address')
                    billing_address2 = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'billing_address2')
                    billing_province = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'billing_province')
                    billing_country = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'billing_country')
                    billing_postal_code = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'billing_postal_code')
                    billing_phone_number = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'billing_phone_number')

                    if is_valid_form([billing_address1, billing_province, billing_country, billing_postal_code,
                                      billing_phone_number]):
                        billing_address = Address(
                            user=self.request.user,
                            street_address=billing_address1,
                            apartment_address=billing_address2,
                            province=billing_province,
                            country=billing_country,
                            postal_code=billing_postal_code,
                            phone_number=billing_phone_number,
                            address_type='B'
                        )
                        billing_address.save()

                        order.billing_address = billing_address
                        order.save()

                        set_default_billing = form.cleaned_data.get(
                            'set_default_billing')
                        if set_default_billing:
                            billing_address.default = True
                            billing_address.save()

                    else:
                        messages.info(
                            self.request, "Please fill in the required billing address fields")
                        return redirect('core:checkout')

                payment_option = form.cleaned_data.get('payment_option')

                if payment_option == 'S':
                    return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='stripe')
                elif payment_option == 'P':
                    return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='paypal')
                else:
                    messages.warning(
                        self.request, "Invalid payment option selected")
                    return redirect('core:checkout')

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
```

Here is the forms.py

```
PAYMENT_CHOICES = (
    ('S', 'Stripe'),
    ('P', 'Paypal')
)


class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    shipping_address = forms.CharField(required=False)
    shipping_address2 = forms.CharField(required=False)
    shipping_province = forms.CharField(required=False)
    shipping_country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)').formfield(
        required=False,
        widget=CountrySelectWidget(attrs={
            'class': 'custom-select d-block w-100'
        }))
    shipping_postal_code = forms.CharField(required=False)
    shipping_phone_number = forms.CharField(required=False)

    billing_address = forms.CharField(required=False)
    billing_address2 = forms.CharField(required=False)
    billing_province = forms.CharField(required=False)
    billing_country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)').formfield(
        required=False,
        widget=CountrySelectWidget(attrs={
            'class': 'custom-select d-block w-100'
        }))
    billing_postal_code = forms.CharField(required=False)
    billing_phone_number = forms.CharField(required=False)

    same_billing_address = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    set_default_shipping = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    use_default_shipping = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    set_default_billing = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    use_default_billing = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    payment_option = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating two routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

When the PayPal radio button is selected, you can have this event trigger javascript to unhide a paypal button container div similar to what's at: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

For your use case, `layout: 'horizontal'` might be best.

There's an example basic HTML/JS implementation combining that with radio buttons at: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/radio

It's worth having the yellow PayPal button and whatever local "alternate" payment method like PP Credit PayPal decides to show the buyer next to it visible by default (radio button preselected, or no radio buttons at all and just have the credit card form also displayed beneath it).  This will increase your conversion, the fewer clicks the better--PayPal's selling point is that sails buyers through a secure checkout in as few clicks as possible.